# windows 10 - Is it going to be easy to recover a bit locker drive D after I format normal windows drive C

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I have a machine with windows 10, I need to reinstall the OS and configure windows 10 as part of an organisation. I have two drives, C for windows and D encrypted with bitlocker. I want to know if reinstalling windows 10 on C drive will affect my other D drive.

Comment: Drive D is a partition or a physical disk?

Comment: Only if you have the recovery key. Is that the case?

Comment: The D is a partition. I have the recovery key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if reinstalling windows 10 on C drive will affect my other D drive.

The BitLocker protection status of a secondary drive is not affected by reinstalling Windows.  As long as you have the recovery key for the drive, the following command in an elevated command prompt, will unlock the drive.  You can also do the same process through File Explorer.

`manage-bde –unlock E: -recoverykey "C:\Backupkeys\recoverykey.bek"`

Source: [manage-bde: unlock](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/manage-bde-unlock)

> The D is a partition.

My answer is based on a few assumptions.  You are not going to format the drive and delete all partitions. I am also making the assumption you will be using Reset or Fresh Start instead of using the WinPE to reinstall Windows.  **If you use the WinPE there is a good chance you will accidentally delete the data partition in question.**  While it's certainly possible to only delete the system partition, and install Windows on it, you must take great care when you do that.  **If the partition protected by BitLocker is accidentally deleted then your data is lost.**

Comment: If this command does not do what you want, or if this answer does not answer your question, then you would need to edit and clarify your question.  Questions submitted within a comment will not be addressed.